# Website Self Destruct from Browser Bar

Tags: php

IS there a file that I can upload onto my website (my website is a website that contains very very very sensitive information) that when navigated to in the browser (www.example.com/script.php) can be executed to delete all files from the folder it is uplaoded into/ I want to be able to delete this information easy as that. Kind of like a Self Destruct Button. MY website is used for testing sensitive equiptment commands for diamond blade cutters. We got almost the perfect cut for a diamond which makes ours very valuable. Our site was hacked and there was nothn gi could do in the backend because the password was changed on us so i want to put a secret file in there that does this.

Comment: Depends on the server configuration.

Comment: Why are such sensitive items available over the public internet in the first place?

Comment: @DCoder  has a point - if you're asking for this; it tends to suggest (no offense intended) you're not a great candidate for securing sensitive information... perhaps you need to hire a security consultant IF this needs to be available online..

Comment: lol its stored online to be viewed by people we want....it is secure as fort knox but my boss wants...a self destruct button. He loves star trek

Comment: if it's fort knox, how were you hacked?

Comment: A 'self-destruct' script will not help you in the slightest to secure the 'sensitive information'. If the security of the webserver is compromised, the best thing you can do is taking the server offline immediately and only bring it back online once all security issues have been fixed.

Comment: @Trent It was overrun by a group of suicide bombers, dual wielding scimitars and a band of wookies

Comment: honestly i get min wage for this crummy job....ill just tell him its secure

Answer (score 1):

i would not recommend that as a solution,
why don't you secure the script instead ?

anyway just for the fun of it here is a function that will delete a folder

```
function deleteAll($directory, $empty = false) {
    $t= time(); // you can also use it to delete old files by subtracting from this

    if(substr($directory,-1) == "/") {
        $directory = substr($directory,0,-1);
    }

    if(!file_exists($directory) || !is_dir($directory)) {
        return false;
    } elseif(!is_readable($directory)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $directoryHandle = opendir($directory);

        while ($contents = readdir($directoryHandle)) {
            if($contents != '.' && $contents != '..') {
                if(filemtime($directory . "/" . $contents) < $t) {
                    $path = $directory . "/" . $contents;

                    if(is_dir($path)) {
                        @deleteAll($path);
                    } else {
                        @unlink($path);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        closedir($directoryHandle);
        if($empty == false) {
            if(!@rmdir($directory)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

(!) be careful when you use it it will DELETE everything you can call it like this `deleteAll(".", true);`

but this is not a solution look into securing your script